# Laravel 5.2 PUT request gives MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, put

So I'm having troubles with a `PUT` request in laravel.

I've done my research and know that you should simulate a `PUT` request with `_method` = `PUT` and change it to `POST` because HTML doesn't support `PATCH` and `PUT`.

However postman is still returning the MethodNotAllowedHttpException, I've also added the url to the `$except` array in the VerifyCsrfToken class. I've also tried adding it as a `GET` variable to the end of the url with no success.

The error log returned by laravel:

```
in RouteCollection.php line 219
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('PUT')) in RouteCollection.php line 206
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('PUT')) in RouteCollection.php line 158
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 802
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 670
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

These are my routes:

```
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                               | Name | Action                                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                                 |      | Closure                                                         | web        |
|        | PUT      | api/user                          |      | App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@createUser                 |            |
|        | POST     | dashboard/admin/updatedate        |      | App\Http\Controllers\AdminsController@updateDate                | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/alerts                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\AlertsController@index                     | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/categorie/{id}          |      | App\Http\Controllers\CategorieController@index                  | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/development             |      | App\Http\Controllers\DevelopmentController@index                | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/home                    |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | web,auth   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | dashboard/login                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/logout                  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 | web        |
|        | POST     | dashboard/password/email          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | dashboard/password/reset          |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/password/reset/{token?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | web,guest  |
|        | POST     | dashboard/register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/register                |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | web,guest  |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard/zone/{id}               |      | App\Http\Controllers\ZoneController@index                       | web,auth   |
+--------+----------+-----------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Here are my routes in script:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
  Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pvn.index');
  });

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::put('/user', 'UsersController@createUser');
  });

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'app'], function () {
    return view('app.map.view');
  });

  Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    Route::auth();
  });
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']], function () {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard'], function () {
      Route::post('/admin/updatedate', 'AdminsController@updateDate');

      Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

      Route::get('/development', 'DevelopmentController@index');
      Route::get('/categorie/{id}', 'CategorieController@index');
      Route::get('/zone/{id}', 'ZoneController@index');
      Route::get('/alerts', 'AlertsController@index');
    });


});
```

postman code:

```
PUT /api/user HTTP/1.1
Host: platformveilignederland.nl
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8dd46b47-ad06-151e-57de-7ddf37ee4f66
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

user=gertje
```

So does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: What route are you doing the request?

Comment: Are you doing the post using x-www-form-urlencoded, selected in Postman's body tab?

Comment: Where is your form code?  What route are you posting to?

Comment: i'm putting to api/user, i'm using postman it's a tool for testing api's. I tried using multiple content types but without success.

Comment: can you post your routes.php file

Comment: "Putting" to api/user, or posting?  We need to see exactly what you are posting.

Comment: nothing atm, empty request with a empty function behind it. just testing my api route. Not that it makes a difference. tried it with request payload and without.

Comment: An empty request would generate a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`, since you only have a `put` route set up.  We're going in circles as we can't see what you're doing.

Comment: Can't post the code because I already tried it all. empty, filled, different content types, different request methods. am thinking it has something to do with the headers being sent and accepted.

Comment: Just a small note - you stated that the **browser** doesn't support `PUT` / `PATCH` methods - it's not, browsers support all methods, even custom named ones. Since you solved the issue, can you make a note to update the question so future visitors don't wrongly conclude that browsers don't support these methods?

Comment: You're right, @Mjh. Altough html doesn't support these methods in their form's. That's what i meant with browsers.

Comment: @SjoerddeWit - ah, I see - yes, you're right. Anyway, I'll stop nitpicking now, have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a problem with my .htaccess, the server didn't allow put and delete request. added these lines to make it work:

```
<Limit GET POST PUT DELETE>
  Allow from all
</Limit>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future